# No resize event on mobile

Tags: javascript, angular, mobile

I try to do some changes on resize inside an Angular 4 application. I use the event *resize* to do this and it works fine on desktop device browsers. The following lines are called inside the constructor of the Angular component which needs to be informed if size changes.

```
const onResize = (e) => { ... };
window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);
```

But it fails on mobile devices (checked on Android 4 tab and Android 6 phone). There is no call of the function, neither on zooming nor on changing the text-size. Maybe this [link](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2013/11/orientationchan.html) may be the cause for the problem.

But how it can be solved?

Comment: This is cause the size is fixed on the phone so it does not change.
If you want to set data based on size try to use `window.screen.width` or height.

Comment: I have checked `window.screen.width` and `window.innerWidth` on phone. Both values are changed if Text-size is changed in browser. Zooming does not change these values. So your suppose that it does not change is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for event which user rotate the phone to landscape or portrait. Here you are: **onOrientationChange**
If you are looking for zoom or some touch event, try [touchy](https://github.com/hotstudio/touchy)

Comment: Event `orientationchange` is detected, helps to handle phone rotating. Event `touchy` is detected when wishing up down, but not on zoom. Changing the text-size does not emit one of these events. So I hope, someone has some solution for my problem to detect all changes which have impact on size.